# Symfony 'master controller' to start session in?

Tags: php, symfony

I have various methods and classes thats call start session, sometimes resulting in the error `"Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent"`

Leaving me to wonder, where would be a good place to start session? Somewhere that only gets called once per request, and somewhere that gets called on every request. Like a master controller?

Comment: Pretty sure you should never be calling session_start yourself in any of your classes. This should be handled by `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` and i would assume is intialized somewhere during boot.

Comment: @prodigitalson shouldve clarified, i am using the symfony session

Answer (score 3):

To start session you should do:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

The [Symfony documentation Sessions chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) says..

> Symfony sessions are designed to replace several native PHP functions.
>   Applications should avoid using session_start(),
>   session_regenerate_id(), session_id(), session_name(), and
>   session_destroy() and instead use the APIs in the following section.

**EDIT**:

Take a look at [symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php) (line 142)

Is `session.use_cookies` enabled in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: I do do this. But sometimes it ends up being called twice which throws the error...

Comment: Are you instnatiating a new session object in various places?

Comment: Sessions are working just fine. Just i call two methods and both methods start/restart it

Comment: You should call $session->start() only once per request.

Comment: Why not remove the session_start() in your classes and injection the SF2 one into it? Just pass @security_context from DIC into your lib, as a contructor or as a setter method